# Is it possible to use msmdpump approach when connecting to azure analysis service

Tags: azure, ssas, azure-analysis-services

For on-prem analysis services (reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0) it is possible to configure http endpoint (which you can use for implementing custom authentication). Is there a way to expose http endpoint also for azure version of analysis services ?

I tried playing with msmdpump.ini and all I got was various errors.

**UPDATE**
Looking at reflected `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll` - the azure endpoint actually IS http endpoint. The communication goes like:

```
POST https://[yourregion].asazure.windows.net/webapi/clusterResolve
{"serverName":"your_as_server_name"}
```

Reply:

```
{"clusterFQDN":"[prefix]-[yourregion].asazure.windows.net",
 "coreServerName":"your_as_server_name",
  "tenantId":"... tenantID"}
```

And then

```
POST https://[prefix]-[yourregion].asazure.windows.net/webapi/xmla
Authorization: Bearer your_azure_ad_jwt_here
x-ms-xmlaserver: your_as_server_name
// xmla request inside the body
```

So in theory one should be able to leverage that to create a http proxy. However neither of those is documented/officially suported.

Comment: I guess it should be possible by publishing web app that uses ISAPI extension. Of course that will be IIS web server with ole db drivers-preinstalled. Going to try it

Comment: Any news? I'm playing with it with no luck for couple of days...

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and made it work for case of Execute (you can use Execute + Statement for most tasks)
With second request you need three more headers (not sure about User-Agent):

```
User-Agent: XmlaClient
SOAPAction: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:Execute
x-ms-xmlacaps-negotiation-flags: 1,0,0,0,0
```